# Combining lazy and eager loading in EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I am wondering if it is possible combining lazy and eager loading.
For example, I have one Web Api controller with GET method that does not need to load related entity data, but I have also another Web Api controller and its method GET needs to retrieve data from related entity.

Is it good practice to combine these two approaches and are there any specific configurations I need to set up?

Comment: It is possible to combine those two, but your specified scenarios can be done using eager loading only. If possible, it's much better to stick to only one approach.

Comment: I'm wondering if this question *might* be a little more opinion-based than "good practice" based...

Comment: Of course it's opinion-based. How can we recommend any good practice without knowing any requirements?

Comment: There is not need to have any requirements, I am just wondering if I have 100 Web Api controllers and each of them has its own GET method, and 50 of them need to retrieve related entities and other 50 does not. How can I achieve so that my application works as fast as it possible.

Comment: The answer to that is different for each case. So there's your answer: yes it is good practice to combine loading strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that.And it's a Good practise too according to the real situation like yours.

When you **don't need** the `Lazyloding` ,on that particular method you can disable it as shown below.

```
public List<PropertyListDto> SearchProperties(AdditionalSearchInput input)
{
   _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;//to remove lazy loading

  ///your code
}
```

**Note :** In Entity Framework 4 and beyond **Lazy Loading is enabled by default**. We can `disable` it globally, on `DbContext` level, or selectively, on `query level` as shown above.

Here is how to do it on `DbContext` level.

```
public partial class MyDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyDBEntities(): base("name=MyDBEntities")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

**Update :** The 50 controllers where you **don't need lazyloding** you can disable it on `constractor` level as shown below.Then you **don't need** to give it on `query level` on each method.I think it's very quick way to implement it :)

```
public class YourAppService : IYourAppService
    {
        private readonly YourDbContext _context;

        public YourAppService(YourDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;//to remove lazy loading
        }
}
```

Comment: Is lazy loading turned on by default? So, If I need use eager loading I will do what you explained right now ?

Comment: Yes,by default it's `on`.Yes when you use the `Eager loading` you can do that as shown above.

Comment: I a case if I do `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`, should I do implement eager loading on each method using _Include_ method or? Based on this configuration what the result of GET method is (related entities are loaded or not)?

Comment: Please see the `Update` section.

Comment: No problem.If you need to know more about this, feel free to ask it again :)